# Build process failed, no corre app en windows

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have this error, it happens when I start my app in windows

> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart(26,30): error G54CF1E69: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'IOStreamedResponse' doesn't allow null. [C:\wamp64\www\ERP-APP\escamet-erp-app\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(245,5): error MSB8066: Compilación personalizada de "C:\wamp64\www\ERP-APP\escamet-erp-app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\128a543f16bc6c7257558b1f9fc0e070\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\wamp64\www\ERP-APP\escamet-erp-app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\0d0db72735d346d8441f4ddf73f1d93f\flutter_assemble.rule" terminada con el código 1. [C:\wamp64\www\ERP-APP\escamet-erp-app\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
> Exception: Build process failed.

It seems that it is an error with the http package

Comment: Try following commands 1. flutter pub cache clean 2. flutter clean 3. flutter pub get 4. flutter run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following commands

1. flutter pub cache clean
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. flutter run

Comment: did not work for me